# PC turned on by itself and sending packages even when turned off

Tags: network

My father told to me that his PC has turned on by itself. I have no idea about what this can be, and this has never occurred before. After this, he turned off the PC and I checked my router, and seen that his PC was sending (but not receiving) few packages even when turned off.

I would like to know if this packages (even in a very little amount) are normal when a PC is turned off.

Besides that, my father is not concerned about security, so I installed a firewall one month ago, and a few days ago I noticed that some connections from his PC to multicast addresses (like 239.255.255.250 and 224.0.0.251) is being blocked buy my firewall, but I blocked inbound and outbound connections from/to these addresses in my father's PC, and today I checked if this configuration stay fine and it looks fine.

Any ideas of what could I do? Both Malwarebytes and RogueKiller reported nothing.

Comment: The easiest answer is that it was not turned off. People think the machine is turned off when only the screen is turned off or it is in "sleep mode". Confirm that it was actually turned off.

Comment: @schroeder It was turned off. My father was watching TV and turned off his PC some minutes before it turned on by itself.

Comment: Maybe the PC entering sleep mode?  I will not make my speculation on Wake-on-LAN,  but if you worry about it, you can go into the system UEFI/BIOS and check whether there is an option to disable it.

Comment: I said that, when I checked my router, I seen that his PC was sending (but not receiving) few packages even when turned off. This could be normal?

Comment: @Mycroft the simple thing is to try to repeat the situation. Turn it off in the same way as before, check to see if there are packets, and see if it turns itself back on. Then try to confirm that your "turning off process" is actually turning it off. Machines that are turned off do not function by definition, so you ar either misunderstanding something or some hacker has completely rewritten the hardware in the computer to prevent the machine from actually turning off.

Comment: @schroeder I saw my father clicking in "shut down" before I check my router, so the PC was really turned off, and when I checked I seen a few packets being sending occasionally.

Comment: and did it shut down or did it apply patches?

Comment: @schroeder It was shut down manually.

Answer (score 2):

Many BIOS support a variant of "Wake on LAN" command. This means, among other things, that there is a minimal network function even when nominally powered off.

More unlikely scenarios could include hidden firmware based malware, but a glitchy wake-on-lan seems more likely.

Comment: This seems the most likely to me. I've personally experienced a lot of frustration from this kind of thing...